# Does java outer class compilation impact the inner class compilation when there is no change in the inner class?

Tags: java

I have to give a patch to the application server when I have a class with an inner class. I did a change only in outer/main class so do I need to replace the class file of inner class along with main class file or just outer class file will suffice the need?

My question is when my class is compiled and two class files generated, one for outer class and one for the inner class, later I changed the code in the outer class and recompiled it. I know outer class bytecode will be changed for sure but will there be any change in inner class bytecode(class file)?

I know this is already been asked but it is not **clearly answered** yet.

Comment: You can easily test this by comparing class files before and after the change.

Comment: thanks, @luc14n0 but do anybody already know it?

Comment: Duplicate questions should not be opened in order to get better answers to existing questions. You should leave a comment there or create a bounty (once you have more reputation).